# Differences between default(int) vs int = 0

Tags: c#

anyone knows if exists any difference between declare an integer variable using:

```
var i = default(int)
```

vs

```
var i = 0;
```

Maybe a small performance difference or other differences?

Thanks to all!

Comment: There is no different of course.  Write readable code, pretty sure the vast majority of programmers favor the explicit 0 usage.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Effectively, there is no difference. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25tdedf5.aspx)

> Specifies the default value of the type parameter. This will be null
>   for reference types and zero for value types.

`int` is a value type, so the expression will resolve to 0.

I would perform the explicit 0 assignment as its a lot more readable.

Comment: Thanks friend for the answer

Answer (score 35):

Here's the IL for the `var i = default(int)` code:

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // i
```

Here's the IL for the `var i = 0;` code:

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // i
```

Seems like it boils down to personal preference.

Comment: Also `var i = new int()` is same.

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference between the two.
In C# there are facilities provided for different situations. This doesn't imply using them in all situations regardless of their logical reason behind it.
For example default is most common in generics since In generic classes and methods, one issue that arises is how to assign a default value to a parameterized type T when you do not know the following in advance.
Although you can use it with primitive types such as int, but you are not suggested to do so, its whole reason of existence is something else.
Use the later one as it is more readable and logical.
You may also want to see [this link on default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

In terms of functionality, no, there is no difference as `0` is the default value for type `int`.

In terms of performance, I'm pretty sure that `default(int)` is replaced by 0 during compile time so the only slight performance hit can happen during compile time, but not runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Another factor could be in the future if (default) definition has been changed in the compiler then your project might break.

Comment: I don't think the default value of int would ever change.

Comment: You are definitely right. However, you are going with the assumption so I am. There is no scientific discussion. I remember that the default value for C language used to be something else - 32767 ?!

Answer (score 3):

I believe both are the same , but may be explicit value will be better , as the way to call default changed from `default(int)` to `default` direct

> int a = default(int);
>
> Beginning with C# 7.1, you can use the default literal to initialize
>   a variable with the default value of its type:
>
> int a = default;

Reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default-values-table